# Как работает стек в Си при вызове функции с возвращаемым значением?

Tags: c

Что произойдет со стеком при вызове функции func(), если выполнится следующий код?

```
char* func(char* p) {
    char buf[MAX_LEN];
    sprintf(buf, "data: %s\n", p);
    return buf;
}
```

Вопрос с собеседования по С/С++

Comment: А это ничего, что функция возвращает указатель на локальную переменную? :)

Comment: А ведь еще бывает так называемый "компилированный стек". :-) Об этом полезно сказать на собеседовании, чтобы задавить всех интеллектом. :-)

Comment: @Harry Пофиг, пляшем.

Comment: Зависит от ABI на конкретную архитектуру и придерживается ли его компилятор, базовые принципы примерно одинаковы, а вот результат может быть разным.

Answer (score 1):

Со стеком произойдет то, что обычно происходит со стеком при вызове любой функции:

- Перед входом в функцию в стеке (возможно) сформируется значение параметра `p`, в стеке запомнится адрес возврата из функции, и затем, непосредственно при входе в функцию, указатель стека сдвинется так, чтобы зарезервировать в нем память для локального массива `buf`.
- В процессе выполнения функции в массиве `buf` (в стеке) будет сформирована некоторая строка. Что это за строка, сколько памяти под нее понадобится и поместится ли она в `buf` сказать невозможно, ибо никакой информации о параметре `p` у нас нет.
- По завершению функции указатель стека вернется обратно в то место, где он был в момент входа в функцию, тем самым вытолкнув из стека регион памяти, занимаемый `buf`. Затем из стека извлечется адрес возврата и (возможно) удалится значение параметра `p`.

Возвращаемое значение функции скалярного типа традиционно формируется в регистре процессора, а не в стеке, т.е. к стеку никакого отношения не имеет.

Comment: "в стеке (возможно) сформируется значение параметра `p`" – возможно потому, что память банально может быть выделена вручную? Или есть что-то более интересное?

Comment: @AivanF. Или передача аргументов через регистры...

Comment: Стек фрейм скорее всего будет утерян при возврате, а данные — это уже интересно, могут быть и перетёрты, если среда запуска помешана на безопасности.

Comment: @AivanF.: Имеется в виду то, что параметры уже давно принято передавать не через стек, а через регистры процессора.